# Symmetrical power supply with two transformers - no symmetric output

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, circuit-design, voltage-regulator

I'm building a **symmetrical power supply** and I ran into a problem with my design. In my simulation, **output isn't symmetric at all**. I chose this design.

[image: The design i chose]

Now the next image is my actual design. Its a linear power supply with current and voltage regulation and **I have one already built and running**, so I wanted to build a second identical one, which should form one symmetrical power supply according to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7t1s.png);

[image]

**Results of the simulation:**

- +U =  0 V
- -U = 25 V
- I figured out +U is 0 V because on **Rz (load)** there are identical voltages at both terminals of the load.
- I suspect the **R18**(current sense rezistor) to be the issue, but dont know how to solve it.

**Conclusion**

I believe I followed design instructions from the first scheme but it isnt working. Could you **please explain the results of the simulation** and **how to edit the scheme** to get it working properly? Thank you very much for your ideas and please forgive my english.

Comment: For one, if your schematic is correct, you have the negative rails of both power supplies connected to G.  This ties the two negative rails together.

Comment: And a well written question (I gave it an up vote).  Enough detail that could see what is going on, and a specific question on which we cold focus.

Comment: Very good work. When one wants "symmetric" supplies (same GROUND), the reference for the negative supply should be ... the "reference" inverted ... which means "complementary" power supply. Just as one designed a "push-pull" amplifier with bipolar power supplies.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't read the handwriting on the two (apparently) voltage regulators in your first diagram. What are their part numbers? From your second diagram I assume that they are the polarity devices (couldn't tell from the handwriting in the first). If so, typical linear voltage regulators cannot be operated "in reverse". You can't make a 12-0-12 V supply with 2 7812 linear regulators. One needs to be a 7912.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy In the first schematic, its just a symbol for whatever design. You can see in second scheme I used complex linear power supply design with OP amps. According to my book and to the now working simulation, this should work well. Just a note: You need two separate second transformer windings for it to work. Its denoted in the second scheme with the **T1 and T2** labels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *Could you please explain the results of the simulation and how to edit
> the scheme to get it working properly*

I think this may be your simulation problem: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir, removing the **upper** ground solved the problem. Even relabeling one of the grounds worked, to indicate that it is not the same ground.